# Applications of van Emde Boas trees?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, van-emde-boas-trees

Are there any applications of [van Emde Boas trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) besides as fast priority queues for integers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

van Emde Boas trees can be used anywhere in place of a normal binary search tree so long as the keys in the search tree are integers in some fixed range.  Thus for applications where you need to be able to find the integer in a set that is closest to some other integer, using a vEB-tree can potentially be faster than using a simple balanced binary search tree.  As an example, of you have a linear layout of stores on some line and want to find the closest store to some particular customer, using a vEB-tree could make the search exponentially faster than the (already fast) BST.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How 'fixed' should the fixed range be? I mean, if it can be any range, then there's no point in mentioning it, right?

Comment: @Cupidvogel van Emde Boas trees need to be constructed with knowledge of an upper bound on the size of the range. There's no upper limit to what that size can be, but once it's chosen, it's fixed.

Comment: @Cupidvogel depends on how much space space your implementation is allowed to take. From wikipedia:
"For small trees the overhead associated with vEB trees is enormous: on the order of sqrt(M). This is one reason why they are not popular in practice. One way of addressing this limitation is to use only a fixed number of bits per level, which results in a trie. Alternatively, each table may be replaced by a hash table, reducing the space to O(n) (where n is the number of elements stored in the data structure) at the expense of making the data structure randomized."